# Limiting Foreign Key Choices in Django Admin *rows*

Tags: python, django

I have two Django Models X and Y that both have a "type" field, and Y is a ForeignKey for X.  When displaying the list (rows) of X, Django automatically shows me a choice box for Y, including all possible instances of Y.  However, I want to limit the ForeignKey choices to those that have the "type" set the same as the current object.

I have looked at plenty of related questions on this, and have learned that one way of accomplishing this is to override the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method of `ModelAdmin`, and because I need to know the type of the current object, I also need to override `get_form` and add a reference to the current object to the request.

This works when editing the form for an individual instance, but does NOT work when loading the admin's table-based view for all instances of the Model.  Apparently it calls `formfield_for_foreignkey`, but not `get_form`, so the object reference that I'm looking for doesn't exist.  Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

[limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) is what you are looking for. It ensures what you want to do at model level rather than in form level. This way the queryset for your forms will be already filtered (no need to override the formfield_for_foreignkey anymore).

Comment: I looked at that option too.  In that case, I would define my ForeignKey like this: limit_choices_to={'type': type}.  That produces a TypeError (int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'IntegerField').  How can I express that I want to use the current value of this field as the limiter? (another post suggested that this isn't possible at the class level)